# How do I get rid of "Obstructed" errors when trying to commit my changes?

Tags: visual-studio, svn, visualsvn

I committed my changes awhile back, but my changes were reverted due to conflicts.  So, now I'm trying to commit my changes again.  I'm basically adding back the same directories and files.  But no matter what I do, the folders always show "Obstructed" when I try and commit using Visual SVN.  I've tried doing a cleanup and update but I still get the errors on the folders.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to resolve the conflicts. Update the relevant folders, and follow the [conflict resolution procedures](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch03s05.html#svn-ch-3-sect-5.4). It's not that scary, I promise :)

Comment: It turns out that I was merging files between 2 local repositories outside of visual studio and I must have corrupted the destination repository by copying some svn files.  I reverted the directories and re-added the directories and was up and running again.